# TFS 2015 On Premise Team Room Alerts

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Does anyone know a way of triggering an email alert when a post or event has been added to a project's team room?

Answer (score 1):

There are no such settings in Email Alert.

However , both of the event in email alert and in Team Room are listening to the same server side event. Simply returns in different ways. Moreover, most of the events which they listen to are the same. Such as Build, Code, WorkItem, Checkin(pull).

[image]
[image]

In other words, you can get the same result of your email when an event has been added to a project's team room by setting the same conditions in your email alter.

Comment: I agree. The Team Room is basically just a subscriber, not a publisher.